# How can Deterministic Pseudo Random Number Generator generate 64 byte hash from 32 byte seed using SHA-256 hashing function?

Tags: random, hash, cryptography, sha256, sha2

SHA-256 hashing function outputs 32 byte hash always. How can I, using 32 byte seed and SHA-256 hashing function to create an 64 byte hash output ?

I've heard that they use technique like this (pseudocode):

```
init_hash = SHA256 (seed)
next_hash = SHA256 (init_hash + 1)
next_hash_vol2 = SHA256 (next_hash + 2)
next_hash_vol3 = SHA256 (next_hash_vol2 + 3)
...
next_hash_volA = SHA256 (next_hash_vol9 + A)
...
next_hash_vol10 = SHA256 (next_hash_volF + 10)
...
...
next_hash_vol64 = SHA256 (next_hash_vol63 + 40)
```

This sounds really nice! But problem is that SHA-256 ALWAYS generates 32 byte output, but I need 64 bytes :(

Comment: Just call the SHA256 function twice making some small change to the seed between the two calls, such as incrementing it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you mean like next_hash = SHA256 (seed).
Then  next_hash + (concatenate) + SHA256 (next_hash + 1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting with a 32 byte seed and a 32 byte hash, you will end up with 32 bytes of entropy no matter how much you expand it.

Given that, then you have many options such as the one @David Schwartz suggested.  Here is a different option in pseudocode:

```
hash64(inputString)
  hash1 = SHA256(inputString)
  hash2 = SHA256(hash1)
  return concatenate(hash1, hash2)
end hash64
```

Many other similar options are possible, such as:

```
hash64(inputString)
  gnirtStupni = reverse(inputString)
  hash1 = SHA256(inputString)
  hash2 = SHA256(gnirtStupni)
  return concatenate(hash1, hash2)
end hash64
```

Essentially, two separate hashes based on the same input, but tweaked so the hashes are not identical. Then concatenate the two hashes.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation! Thumb up!